# How read response from a stringRequest using volley?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm using volley to post/get some data intro a website, but I'm having problem reading the response..the response has two values, State and Message.

This is what i have tried to read the response

> response[0] 
>   response.State

Can someone explainme what am I doing wrong?

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response is: "+ response);
    }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Algo esta mal");
    }
})
```

> Response is : {"State":"FAIL","Message":"Theres an error"}

Comment: In that case your request is wrong not the way you're reading it
also since the response is a string it wont act as an array or object, its a string.

Comment: try posting your `server` code as well.